# How to use a specific Git submodule revision per local branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I have a git repo with a dev and a master branch. Now I am trying to use a different revision of a submodule in each branch. So for example I do this:

```
git checkout master
cd submodule
git checkout v1.0
cd ..
git commit -a -m "now using submodule v1.0"
git checkout dev
cd submodule
git checkout v2.0
cd ..
git commit -a -m "let's try submodule v2.0"
```

Now after that I checkout the master branch and it seems the submodule in the master branch is also pointing to the v2.0 commit instead of v1.0.

I've read quite a lot about git submodules, but it still seems a bit abstract to me. Could anybody explain how to use a submodule properly in this particular case? (git version 1.7.3.1)

Thanks!

Comment: Does `git commit -a` actually fix up the submodule reference?  We gave up on submodules back in the git 1.5 days (because we wanted something rather different anyway) so I never used `commit -a` on them.  Always had to carefully `git add submodule` first.

Comment: @torek thanks for your reply! Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. Also I tried creating a new branch in the submodule (like: `git checkout -b branch-1.0 v1.0` on master and `git checkout -b branch-2.0 v2.0`) but that didn't work neither. It seems that submodules shouldn't be used like this, so what would be an alternative in this situation?

Comment: I did a little reading-up after that; it looks like submodule support has evolved a lot since 1.5, and is evolving even more now.  So, some things depend on your exact version of git.  As in the existing answer though the main problem was your (lack of) `submodule update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing branches in the super-project isn't going to change the contents in the submodule; the branch change will only change the super-project's commit reference for its submodule.  You need to do:

```
git submodule update
```

after checking out a branch in the super-project.  The 'update' will change the submodule to reference the proper commit.  Here is an example:

```
ebg@taiyo(84)$ git checkout master
M test1
Switched to branch 'master'
ebg@taiyo(85)$ git submodule update
Submodule path 'test1': checked out '16aff6eed3998f14eb96b4f61666b47160de0e6b'
ebg@taiyo(89)$ git checkout top-other
M test1
Switched to branch 'top-other'
ebg@taiyo(90)$ git submodule update
Submodule path 'test1': checked out 'af33fca078dbb1fa415f9ea7fafb1b92cad1c6ae'
ebg@taiyo(91)$ git status
# On branch top-other
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it. Actually I tried that before and then it didn't work, but I think I forgot to do `git submodule init` the first time...